# In Hello World flask app, Flask cannot find the app

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am running the minimal Hello World app from the Flask documentation. The code is below. I get `no module named "flask.hello."` The traceback is also below. I would like to know how to direct the flask to resolve the location of the app. The name of the source file is hello.py. I set

```
FLASK_APP='hello.py' and PYTHONPATH="."
```

I start Flask with the command:

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000
```

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello world!"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.hello'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 338, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 326, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 314, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/home/anna_user2/.venv/projects/web-plots/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 250, in locate_app
    raise NoAppException('Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name))
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "flask.hello".
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it like this from the directory where you have `hello.py`:

```sh
FLASK_APP='hello.py' PYTHONPATH="." flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000
```

There's a typo in your code:

```py
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Fixed typo. Ran it as above. Same message. It is looking for flask.hello and whatever the namespace flask is (and I would like to know), it doesn't contain hello or hello.py. What else could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My working directory was called "flask" which apparently confused flask. When I renamed it to flask_dir, all works.

Answer (score 0):

Change `FLASK_APP='hello.py'` to `FLASK_APP='hello'`

Comment: Same error message results when I change to FLASK_APP='hello'